# What is this action called? He is teasing me?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> **[tease](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/tease_1?q=tease)** [intransitive, transitive] tease (somebody) | tease (somebody) + speech to laugh at somebody and make jokes about them,
>   either in a friendly way or in order to annoy or embarrass them
>
> Don't get upset—I was only teasing.
>
> I used to get teased about my name.

---

A child often sticks out his/her tongue to others to look down on them. See the picture

[image]

**What is that action called: "*He is teasing me*"?**

Comment: "He's sticking out his tongue at me"! Teasing usually involves speech, and that child looks too young to talk much (perhaps even too young to be putting out his tongue with intent to be rude).

Comment: @KateBunting, it is just a picture for depicting the action. Just see him as a toddler.

Comment: (Picture now changed from a baby to a toddler.) We just call it sticking/putting out the tongue [see this definition](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stick-put-your-tongue-out) . In a young child it's just cheeky, in an older person a rather childish form of rudeness or defiance.

Comment: @KateBunting, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: Poking out your tongue in this way can sometimes be a way of “teasing” someone (provoking or gently annoying them) especially if repeated, but when native speakers see this picture “teasing” is not the first thing we think of, as Kate Bunting suggests.